# Rails: view loop refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

This is horrible code, I know. How can I move it into the model when it's based on each record in a collection?

```
<% @brands.each do |b| %>
  <% booleans = Preference.columns.select { |c| c.type == :boolean }.map(&:name) %>
  <% trues = booleans.select { |name| b.preference.send(name) == true } %>
  <%= trues.to_sentence.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I am glad to help, but not to reverse engineer

Comment: This returns a list of an association's columns that are true.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you will get the result of the last element of the list, because this: trues = booleans.select { |name| b.preference.send(name) == true }
You don't want to use "trues +="? Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: It definitely returns a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the logic into your model:

```
# app/models/brand.rb
def self.trues
  self.all.each do |b| # OR whatever collection you're trying to iterate through
    booleans = Preference.columns.select {|c| c.type == :boolean}.map(&:name)
    trues = booleans.select {|name| b.preference.send(name) == true}
    return trues
  end
end
```

Then, display the returned value in your view:

```
# view
<%= Brand.trues.to_sentence.humanize %>
```

As a matter of convention, you may want to store the model convenience method to an instance variable in your controller, then render the instance variable from within your view:

```
# controller action
@trues = Brand.trues

# view
<%= trues.to_sentence.humanize %>
```

Comment: While I changed a couple of things in your solution, this definitely got me on the right track. Thanks!